# How do I detect if my workstation is already locked in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, windows-server-2008

I have reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-if-my-workstation-is-locked) and it would help me identify when the lock event actually happens. But I need to be able to check the current status without capturing the event. Is there a property somewhere I could access for this, or something that would let me infer that the workstation is locked?

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434830/how-do-i-check-if-my-workstation-is-locked

Comment: https://brutaldev.com/post/checking-if-the-workstation-is-locked

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, thank you - that worked for me. If you'd like to add it as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @John Straka: that's no *my* answer, so let it stay a *comment*.