# Checking for workstation lock/unlock change with c#

Tags: c#, windows, session-state, environment

**DUPLICATE:** [How can I programmatically determine if my workstation is locked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980)

How can I detect (during runtime) when a Windows user has locked their screen (Windows+L) and unlocked it again. I know I could globally track keyboard input, but is it possible to check such thing with environment variables?

Comment: The answers to this question might provide a starting point for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980

Comment: Thanks to everyone. You were very helpful as always :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this notification via a WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE message. You must notify Windows that you want to receive these messages via WTSRegisterSessionNotification and unregister with WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification.

These posts should be helpful for a C# implementation.

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wtsapi32.WTSRegisterSessionNotification

http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2005/05/17/418891.aspx

http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/276963-trapping-when-workstation-locked

Comment: -1: The managed code version of this was posted before the Win32 version was... why is this even marked as the correct answer?

Comment: IMO, pinvoke is a last case solution when using .NET.  It's better to use methods built into the Framework first.

Comment: I don't disagree, I just wasn't aware there was an alternative .net method. I've no idea why you cry babies see it as a reason to start downvoting though.

Answer (score 20):

A [SessionSwitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.sessionswitcheventhandler.aspx) event may be your best bet for this. Check the [SessionSwitchReason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.sessionswitchreason.aspx) passed through the [SessionSwitchEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.sessionswitcheventargs.aspx) to find out what kind of switch it is and react appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use `ComponentDispatcher`** as an alternative way to get those events.

Here's an example class to wrap that.

```
public class Win32Session
{
    private const int NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION = 0;
    private const int WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE = 0x2b1;
    private const int WTS_SESSION_LOCK = 0x7;
    private const int WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK = 0x8;

    public event EventHandler MachineLocked;
    public event EventHandler MachineUnlocked;

    public Win32Session()
    {
        ComponentDispatcher.ThreadFilterMessage += ComponentDispatcher_ThreadFilterMessage;
    }

    void ComponentDispatcher_ThreadFilterMessage(ref MSG msg, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE)
        {
            int value = msg.wParam.ToInt32();
            if (value == WTS_SESSION_LOCK)
            {
                OnMachineLocked(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            else if (value == WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK)
            {
                OnMachineUnlocked(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnMachineLocked(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler temp = MachineLocked;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, e);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnMachineUnlocked(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler temp = MachineUnlocked;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You absolutely don't need WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE 
Just use internal WTTS apis.