# How to know when a user console is locked or has logged "back into" windows

Tags: c#, authentication

This is in regards to applications that run in the taskbar but should be applicable to standard apps, Winforms, WPF, etc.

> **Question:**  I am after some method (preferably via managed code) to be notified when a user either has their screen "locked" while my app is running and/or know when they log back in.

*GMail Notifier* does this sort of thing for example, if my PC is locked for a while when I log in again it shows a list of emails that arrived since locking the PC. I'm looking to replicate that kind of functionality.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603484/checking-for-workstation-lock-unlock-change-with-c

Comment: @Mike Daniels, that helped too - it pointed me to `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents` but I had not realised that it included the `SessionSwitch` event. Will need to test it out a bit more... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question mentioned by Mike Daniels has answers:

[Checking for workstation lock/unlock change with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603484/checking-for-workstation-lock-unlock-change-with-c-sharp)

The one I prefer is using is `SessionSwitchReason`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.sessionswitchreason.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You want to hook into the [System Event Notification Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185680%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and subscribe to the ISensLogon DisplayLock/DisplayUnlock events.

Comment: Do you know of a good managed implementation using `ISensLogon`?

Comment: I don't know of an explicitly managed implementation, but there's an example implementation in Python at http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/track-session-events.html