# C# - getting information about Windows user local session

Tags: c#, windows

I'm writing a program and I want it to stop working when user is Locking his account. Can I somehow get those informations? I've tried to google it, but I couldn't find  an answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293286/how-to-get-windows-unlock-event-in-c-sharp-windows-application

Comment: Note that as per the linked question, the [SystemEvents.SessionSwitch event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch.aspx) provides a [SessionSwitchReason](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.sessionswitchreason(v=vs.110).aspx), you will want to look for SessionLock (and SessionUnlock if you want to resume automatically)