# How to check if Windows login screen is displayed (in .NET)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, authentication, session-state

Is there any way to recognize if login screen is displayed ?

I trued to use OpenInputDesktop function but it not reliable (sometime it works but sometimes not)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr OpenInputDesktop(uint dwFlags, bool fInherit, uint dwDesiredAccess);

var handle = OpenInputDesktop(0, false, 0);
var locked = handle == null || handle == 0;
```

My exact case is:
Windows 10 starts all previously ran programs with user session after OS reboot.
I dont want my program to do anything until Windows login screen is displayed / user unlock  his session

Comment: You can listen for [lock and unlock events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12293351/219933) and act on it

Comment: This will only if my app will be run after real user login (user login to OS then locks session). My issue is app starts when session is already locked –

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock)
            {
                // Do what you want here as the system is locked
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unlocked by: {0}", Environment.UserName);
            }
        };
```

Comment: This will only if my app will be run after real user login (user login to OS then locks session). My issue is app starts when session is already locked