# Run an exe whenever a user reconnects to a disconnected user session

Tags: windows

On a windows 8 machine, how can I execute a program whenever a user reconnects to a disconnected session?

The user might walk away from the machine, and the lock screen kicks in. I would like to execute something when they login again to the disconnected session.

This is not a fresh login, but a reconnection to their existing session.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WM_WTSESSION_CHANGE provides this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383828(v=vs.85).aspx

Related SO posts can be found with samples: [Checking for workstation lock/unlock change with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603484/checking-for-workstation-lock-unlock-change-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks! Whipped up some c# code and it's working like a charm