# identify windows user with blocked session

Tags: python, windows

My team uses one computer, and everyone has a different windows user.

I run a python process which requieres to know if my session is locked or not.

I'm using psutils to try and figure out this. with something like this.

```
import time
import psutil


time.sleep(5) # <--- It gives me time to lock my session to check the output below

# with this block I check the usernames with "LogonUI.exe" running
for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name', 'username']):
    if proc.info['name'] == "LogonUI.exe":
        print(f"LogonUI.exe is running in username: '{proc.info['username']}'")

# This was an attempt to do the validation
print(any(proc.info['name'] == "LogonUI.exe" for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name', 'username']) if proc.info['username'] == 'myUser'))

print(any(proc.info['name'] == "LogonUI.exe" for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name', 'username']) if proc.info['username'] == 'anotherUser'))
```

The attempt to do the validation did not worked because "LogonUI.exe" always run when `proc.info['username']` is `None`. Therefore the `proc.info['username']` approach was inneficient.

and actually when my session is blocked and the session of another user is also locked there are 2 "LogonUI.exe" running with different PID

What I want to achieve is even possible?

Comment: LogonUI.exe can keep running after unlocking a device too, so it's not a good choice for this. Depending on your version of windows, you can check for `lockapp.exe`, which does run in locked user sessions. The "correct" way to handle this is to register for wtsapi32 `SessionSwitch` system events: https://stackoverflow.com/a/603527/7411885