# How do I detect a Lock This Computer command from a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, desktop, locking

Would prefer an answer in C#, .Net 3.5 using WPF (Windows Forms also okay)

I have an application that is essentially a toolbar window or tray icon.  It needs to detect if a user locks his/her workstation and walks away in order to update the person's status in a centralized system.

I can detect a session switch or a logout easily enough, using the SystemEvents, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to detect or receive an event on Lock.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-if-my-workstation-is-locked

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When you handle the [`Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionSwitch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch(VS.85).aspx) event (which it sounds like you're already doing to detect logout), check to see if the `Reason` is [`SessionSwitchReason`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.sessionswitchreason.aspx)`.SessionLock`:

```
 using Microsoft.Win32;
 // ...
 // Somewhere in your startup, add your event handler:
    SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += 
       new SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch);
 // ...

 void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
 {
     switch(e.Reason)
     {
         // ...
         case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock:
            // Do whatever you need to do for a lock
            // ...
         break;
         case SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock:
            // Do whatever you need to do for an unlock
            // ...
         break;
         // ...
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to [P/Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/platform-invoke-examples) [`WTSRegisterSessionNotification`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wtsapi32.WTSRegisterSessionNotification).

Comment: Is there a reason to do this instead of handling the SystemEvents.SessionSwitch?

Comment: Only if you're unaware of SessionSwitch. I was until now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something from CodeProject.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/DetectWindowslockunlock.aspx