# Detect if desktop is locked

Tags: winapi, desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I programmatically determine if my workstation is locked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-if-my-workstation-is-locked)

What is the best way to determine if the desktop is locked for the currently logged in user? I looked in MSDN and couldn't find any API calls to detect this. Did I miss something, or is there no simple call I can use?

Answer (score 16):

The answer depends on whether you want to know if the desktop is locked *now*, or if you want to be notified when the desktop gets locked (and, presumably, unlocked). It also depends on how you're planning to receive said notifications.

- If you really want a one-off test, then the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-if-my-workstation-is-locked/44987#44987) uses [`OpenDesktop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684303(VS.85).aspx) and [`SwitchDesktop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686347(VS.85).aspx) to open a handle to the default desktop and activate it - if this fails then it's a good sign that the desktop is locked right now.
- If you want notification on lock/unlock, and you have a user-mode application with a window and a message pump, then you need to call [`WTSRegisterSessionNotification()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383841(VS.85).aspx) and catch the `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE` message.
- If you want notifications, and you're running as a Windows service, then you can register for session change events by calling `SetServiceStatus()` and adding [`SERVICE_ACCEPT_SESSIONCHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685996(VS.85).aspx) to `dwControlsAccepted` in your status structure. You will then receive callbacks to your own service control [`HandlerEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683241(VS.85).aspx) function with `dwControl` set to `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook the [WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383828(VS.85).aspx) message

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WTSRegisterSessionNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383841(VS.85).aspx)  with WTS_SESSION_LOCK

Answer (score -1):

Former answers are wrong (status changes)
Use the WTS api (islocked)
It's used internally by Windows. Always See on [Win32 group](http://news://nntp.aioe.org/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32) for Windows Internal (MS)