# How to identify the keyboard keys using C#

Tags: c#, keyboard, key, identify

I have an C# application runing at the back ground. Now i want to stop this application when the system is locked. how can i do that. Any help regarding this is really appreciated.

Thanks Hougen for the solution. could you please suggest me should we include any Dlls to handle "Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionSwitch" this event? And in which layer this code should reside. I guess it is in Business layer. Any sugeestion regading this?

Comment: What does your question have to do with the keyboard?

Comment: Are you thinking about catching Win+L keyboard combination? I don't think that would solve your problem since the computer can still get locked using other methods...

Comment: Do you mean locked, as in Win+L, or locked as in frozen, crashed?

Comment: Well, if the system is crashed I think you don't need to worry about running applications anymore :-)

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-if-my-workstation-is-locked

Comment: @Johannes Rössel - I think he means when the account is locked and you are required to type a password in to unlock it.

Comment: It's usually best to put the actual problem you are trying to solve in the title, not the problems you are having with a proposed problem. You can, obviously, then include your proposed solution and it's problem in the question. Currently anyone who knows how to identify when the system is locked but doesn't know how to hook keys will overlook your question when they actually have a valid alternative solution.

Answer (score 9):

Easy. Make an event handler for the

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionSwitch
```

event. In it, check the `SessionSwitchEventArgs.Reason` property for the value `SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock`.

**Shyam**: sorry for not coming back to you right away. You shouldn't have to include any special DLLs. The `SystemEvents` class is in the System assembly. Whether this handler belongs in the business layer - I guess it belongs in whatever project contains your service class - the one that inherits from WindowsService.

```
public MyService()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;
}

void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
{
    if (_isRunning)
    {
        // Pause
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I will try with this approach and let you know.

Comment: should we include any Dll's to handle this event?

Comment: Can you suggest me in which layer this event should be raised?