# C# Form Doesn't get minimized on microsoft windows when the workstation is locked

Tags: c#, windows

In my application I need to minizime to tray (doing stuff like visible=false, FormWindowState = minimized etc.) automatically after some time.

The problem is, that when Windows is locked when this code executes, it doesn't happen
(I'm guessing that while Windows is locked all form operations doesn't take place or something)

Does anyone know what can I do?

Comment: I think you should make it clearer that it is Microsoft Windows (as in the operating system) that is locked (via Windows Key + L), not the application's window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to this question: [How can I programmatically determine if my workstation is locked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980)

When your app needs to minimize to the tray, set a flag. When the session unlock occurs, check the flag and, if set, perform the minimize again.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do, run the time consuming task with help of the [BackGroundWorker](http://dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker), so your UI stays responsive.

Comment: That is not the problem here. The OP talks about the workstation being locked, not the app being unresponsive.

Comment: That's indeed what the OP is trying to communicate, but it wasn't communicated well, imho.