# Ignore first touch event when screen saver is enabled - Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, screensaver, windows-screensaver

Is there any solution to prevent the first touch event when the screen saver is enabled on Windows?

The problem is when screen saver is on if the user touches the screen, there is a chance to perform some action (press the button, etc) of an always full screen running application.

The application is written in WPF, so I'm thinking about creating a user control that would catch the first click and after that disappear from the screen. When the screen saver is on again, the user control would be activated again.

I'm wondering if there is some more elegant solution in Windows settings for this issue?

Comment: Input goes to the window under the cursor. If the screen saver is running, it covers the entire display. I doubt that there is a chance that the system occasionally tunnels input through the screen saver.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I would not ask this if it did not happen.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953297/detecting-if-the-screensaver-is-active-and-or-the-user-has-locked-the-screen-in), or the one it links to might have some level of solution for detecting if the screansaver is running. There's also  [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-tell-if-the-screen-saver-is-active/), but it's a bit... ugly.