# Strange Wpf Ballon behavior after unlocking pc

Tags: wpf, balloon

I have a wpf application that runs some threads every x minutes and I noticed that if I block the pc and than unblock it after some time, all the balloons messages that were supposed to display during the time my pc was locked are displayed when I unlock the pc (like they were waiting for the gui to come back).
Is that a normal behaviour?
Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether or not this is intended behavior but I think it is justified in most cases.

[Here is a way to find out if the PC is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-if-my-workstation-is-locked) so you can suppress popups (if that is what you want)