# Notify a background process upon windows login

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, winapi

I have a C# application running in a background thread that needs to be notified when the SAME user logs in to the system .

Ex :

1 . User logs into the system

2 . User starts the application in the background .

3 . The application runs / performs its task.

4 . Now suppose the user went out for lunch and locked his computer .

5 . The user comes back and unlocks his computer .

6 . The application now needs to be notified that the user is back again and get up and start performing its tasks.

How can the Step 6 above be performed so that the application comes to know that the user has re-logged in and now it needs to begin.  Can i register for some Windows notification .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do that by detecting that the computer is not idle anymore or is unlocked.

Check this out: [How can I programmatically determine if my workstation is locked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-if-my-workstation-is-locked)